# List web services - some methods don't work when file name with absolute Url is formed with server name rather than IP address

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, moss, wss, sharepoint-api

I'm using SharePoint List web services to have some queries on SharePoint server. It seems work fine when providing absolute URL with IP address where such input parameters required. For example, `http://192.168.1.114/sites/myteam/Shared Documents/foo.txt`. However, it throw SoapServerException if it was replaced with: `http://servername/sites/myteam/Shared Documents/foo.txt`.

I experienced those problems when I call `CheckInFile` method. If I input file name with IP address it works fine. If I input file name with server name, it throws a `SoapServerException`.

The same problem occurred when I call `UpdateListItems`. I use the string parameter as below:

```
string strBatch = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'>" +
"<Field Name='ID'>3</Field>" +   
"<Field Name='FSObjType'>0</Field>" + 
"<Field Name='FileRef'>" + sFileName + "</Field>" +
"</Method>";
```

If I replace `sFileName` with absolute URL with IP address, it works fine. If I replaced `sFileName` with absolute URL with server name, it returned a XML node with error code of 0x81020030 and error message as below:

> Invalid file name. The file name you specified could not be used.  It
>   may be the name of an existing file or directory, or you may not have
>   permission to access the file.

We are not sure if this problem is brought by List web services or our DNS settings is incorrect. Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check you `Alternate Access Mappings` in Central Administration. You have to make sure that it contains a proper host name reference - the one you are trying to refer here.

Comment: Yes, I checked AAM which indicated to be correct. The strange thing is that CheckOutFile works but CheckInFile doesn't work always with the identical settings...